Projection of vectors from starting basis onto orthogonal complement
Gram-Schmidt process allows us to produce a basis $\{w_1,...,w_n\}$ starting from a basis $\{v_1,...,v_n\}$. If I define $W_j$ to be the subspace generated by $\{w_1,...,w_j\}$ for $j=1,..,n.$ Can I say that $w_{j+1}$ is the projection of $v_{j+1}$ onto the orthogonal complement of $W_j$? For which values of $j$ does this hold?
Do I need to use induction here?

Not quite. $w_{j + 1}$ is the vector obtained by normalizing the projection of $v_{j + 1}$ to $W_j^{\perp}$ to unit length
